# Extra CPU usage by Windows 10

Tags: cpu, process, cpu-usage, malware-removal

I've have been using windows for such a long time but having a doubt that why would cpu be used even during idle .

Please check the screenshot [image: here]

How could be that be possible only one user is logged in and using 17% of cpu but total cpu usage is 20% some times it is reaching limits like 75% of user usage and 100% total usage

Can please help with this . Is this normal or something like malware eating my cpu....?

Comment: System processes are of course not accounted as user CPU usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 has a lot of background processess that kick in mostly when user interaction and/or demand are low. Processess like telemetry or windows update can take a lot of cpu time, so that's probably what you're seeing there. If you want to disable those, there are tools out there that can help you with that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: However, the process on the screenshot is quite a big one. If that's on idle, you should check for malware (with malwarebytes for instance).

Comment: I actually have cleaned the pc but still I am feeling lag ....

Comment: What have you done to clean it? Don't mean to question your ways, just want more info. Keep in mind that all utility programs for windows actually _try_ to clean it, but by definition it's a SO designed to fail (how would they sell the next version if it wasn't?), so formatting/restore is always a good (and long, and tiring, I know) option.

Comment: using malwarebytes

Comment: You should use more than one tool, there's also [ccleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) and [panda cloud cleaner](http://pandacloudcleaner.pandasecurity.com). But if none of those work for you, consider the option of formatting the drive and reinstall windows (I said formatting and reinstalling, not windows's restore option - if the image is infected and malware does that today, you'll be in the starting point again).